# CodeIgniter + Smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I have a problem with connecting CI and Smarty.
I make everything in [this](http://sunwebexpert.com/books/detail/PHP/integrating-smarty-and-codeigniter.html) manual, but when I try open a page I see:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'view/index.tpl' <-- thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci/application/libraries/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 129

Where I can change destination folder?

I also want to add, that I made a view file in the views folder.

Answer (score 4):

[That manual](http://sunwebexpert.com/books/detail/PHP/integrating-smarty-and-codeigniter.html) is for CodeIgniter 2. Update to CodeIgniter 3 and follow these steps:

1. Download CodeIgniter 3
2. Download Smarty 3 and put its content in 'application/third_party/smarty' folder
3. Create 'Custom_smarty.php' file in 'application/libraries' and add this code:

   ```
   <?php
   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

   class Custom_smarty extends Smarty {

     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH.'views/templates/');   
       $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH.'views/templates_c/');
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Create 'templates' & 'templates_c' folders inside 'application/views' folder
5. Create simple 'test.tpl' file in 'application/views/templates' folder
6. Open 'autoload.php' in 'application/config' folder and add:

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('custom_smarty');
   ```
7. Inside a controller write `$this->custom_smarty->display('test.tpl');`
8. If you are working on localhost set the permissions: `sudo chmod -R 777 templates_c`. Otherwhise contact your hosting service, if you catch the error Unable to write file. First be sure templates_c folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find. It's view/templates but i have a new error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file application/views/compiled/wrt549692a6e7c983_16652543 <-- thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci/application/libraries/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 46

I create  a view/compiled folder but smarty cant make file them(?) perrmissions(?)

EDIT.
Ok, all is ok. I dont have permissions for few folders.